# Can binary data be used in ordinal regression models?

Tags: r, modeling, binary-data, ordinal-data

Basically I have some code which runs a lot of calculations originally on some ordinal response variable and some predictor variables, and it is based on the VGAM R package. As such, it seems like it is optimized for the `propodds` family when using the `vglm` function. I guess I could spend time (but I don't know what) and try to optimize it for a binary logistic response variable, but since my response variable is, I guess, somewhat ordinal, i.e. it's an "you have this disease or you don't", I was wondering if that would work on a ordinal based regression like this one ? Or is that a big fat no go ?

Comment: Why not just do regular logistic regression? You don't have to write any code, just use any of the many functions in R that already does this.

Comment: The problem is that my data set contains what I would call a lot of highly correlated variables. Fx, let's say I want to predict if there is going to be rain. I then measure the temperature at different altitudes, and the humidity at different altitudes. Each of these groups would most likely be very correlated, but I only want to use one variable (if any) of each group in my model. Not all variables. So kind of a variable reduction before doing LASSO to further reduce the variables. And as far as I know, LASSO is not very good for highly correlated variables. And this script does this :)